# C++ conditionally call functions based on type of the template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Suppose that I have a couple of functions to process different types of arguments. For example `processInt` for processing `int` variables and  `processString` for processing `std::string` variables.

```cpp
int processInt(int i) 
{
    return i;
}

string processString(string s)
{
    return s;
}
```

And, I have a template function called `foo` which takes either of `int` or `std::string` as argument. And inside this function I need to conditionally call the `processInt` or `processString` based on the variable type sent to it as the argument. The `foo` function would look like this:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
T foo(T value)
{
    T variable;
    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value) 
    {
        variable = processInt(value); 
    }
    else if (std::is_same<T, string>::value)
    {
        variable = processString(value);
    }
    return variable;
}

int main() {
    string s = "Abc";
    int i = 123;
    cout << foo(s) << " " << foo(i) << endl;     
}
```

However, with the above `foo` function I get the following errors:

```cpp
error: no matching function for call to 'processInt'
                variable = processInt(value); 
                           ^~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' requested here
    cout << foo(s) << " " << foo(i) << endl;    
            ^
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to 'int' for 1st argument
int processInt(int i) 
    ^
error: no matching function for call to 'processString'
                variable = processString(value);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'foo<int>' requested here
    cout << foo(s) << " " << foo(i) << endl;    
                             ^
note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') for 1st argument
string processString(string s)
       ^
```

Source code: https://godbolt.org/z/qro8991ds

How could I do this correctly to conditionally call functions based on type of the template parameter in generic functions?

### EDIT

I like to use a single `foo` function without overloading or specializations as otherwise there may be some code duplications. The `foo` function may have lot of lines. But, the difference between code for `int` and `string` will be a single line.

Comment: use `if constexpr`

Comment: And `"Abc"` is not an `std::string`.

Comment: why not use an overloaded function? in that case the processor will just know what type of function to call within the template

Comment: @user7860670  seems like `if constexpr` is a cleaner solution. However, I need to solution that would work with C++11  :(

Comment: The idea makes not much sense in my eyes! Use a normal overload instead of a template, The sense of templates is to use common code for multiple types not fully different code for each.

Comment: @Klaus @onyambu I needed to use a single `foo` function as there may be some code duplications. The `foo` function may have lot of lines. But, the difference between code for `int` and `string` will be a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All branches should be valid, even if branch is not taken.
C++17 has `if constexpr` which would solve your issue

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T value)
{
    T variable;
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) 
    {
        variable = processInt(value); 
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, string>::value)
    {
        variable = processString(value);
    }
    return variable;
}
```

For pre-c++17, you might use overload to obtain similar results (tag dispatching for more complex cases):

```
int foo(int value)
{
    return processInt(value);
}

std::string foo(const std::string& value)
{
    return processString(value);
}

template <typename T
    // possibly some SFINAE to allow some conversion with above functions
    /*,  std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<std::string, T>, bool> = true */>
T foo(T value)
{
    return T{};
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For something like this I would suggest templates and specialization:

```
// Declare base template
template<typename T>
T process(T);

// Specialization for integers
template<>
int process(int value)
{
    // ... code to process integers...
}

// Specialization for strings
template<>
std::string process(std::string value)
{
    // ... code to process strings...
}
```

Then the `foo` function simply becomes

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T value)
{
    return process(value);
}
```

---

Optionally plain old overloading should work just as well.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, you can use immediately-invoked lambda and `if constexpr` to do this

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T value) {
  auto variable = [&value]{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
      return processInt(value);
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
      return processString(value);
  }();

  // use variable

  return variable;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bK6e9PnaT)

Comment: Why are you using a lambda? It works just the same without? https://godbolt.org/z/9hbv7E536

Comment: @AlanBirtles It's unclear if the OP still needs to use `variable` in the function body.

Comment: Even in that case a lambda is not needed https://godbolt.org/z/6EczhnfTe

Comment: @AlanBirtles Yes, but this requires that `T` must be default constructible.

Comment: Given that's how they're using it in the question I'd presume it is default construcible. Either way your answer would be improved with your reasoning for introducing the added syntax complexity of the lambda